# How to use a compiled shared library from one Cython extension in another extension?

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I am building a mathematical library. Most of the code is implemented in Python using `numpy` and `scipy`, but some computational heavy parts like simulation models or random processes sampling are written in C++ and integrated into Python using Cython.

All the C++ code is organized in multiple libraries. Most common parts are in a single core library, while custom models reside in separate libraries. The C++ code is built in such a way, that users may use it without Python if they only need the simulation models or the core functions. If users need, say, model `A`, then they need to link their executable against `libmodel_A` and `libcore`.

The question is, is it possible to reflect separate C++ libraries with Cython, without the need to include the core library into each separate extension?

---

To make things clear, here is a minimal example (the example code is also available at github: https://github.com/larioandr/dummy-cython-exts-deps).

```
.
├── cpp_src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.cpp
│   │   └── app.h
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── core.cpp
│   │   └── core.h
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── Makefile
├── dummy
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── __init__.pxd
│   │   ├── py_app.pxd
│   │   └── py_app.pyx
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── __init__.pxd
│   │   ├── py_core.pxd
│   │   └── py_core.pyx
│   └── __init__.pxd
└── setup.py
```

The C++ code is inside `cpp_src`, the Python package is in `dummy`. `core` is a library that can be used by itself and is also required by the `app`. C++ library:

- `cpp_src/core/core.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef LIB_CORE_H
#define LIB_CORE_H

void greet();  // this function can be called by the user
int someServiceFun();  // this function is used by libapp

#endif // LIB_CORE_H
```

- `cpp_src/core/core.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "core/core.h"
#include <cstdio>

void greet() { printf("Hello from core\n"); }
int someServiceFun() { return 42; }
```

- `cpp_src/app/app.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef APP_APP_H
#define APP_APP_H

int getTheAnswer();

#endif
```

- `cpp_src/app/app.cpp`

```cpp
#include "app/app.h"
#include "core/core.h"  // <-- here we reference libcore!

int getTheAnswer() { return someServiceFun(); }
```

- `cpp_src/Makefile` (real code uses CMake, skipping it for simplicity):

```
all: main core/libcore.a app/libapp.a

main: main.cpp core/libcore.a app/libapp.a
    g++ -o main main.cpp core/libcore.a app/libapp.a

core/libcore.a: core/core.cpp core/core.h
    g++ -c core/core.cpp -o core/core.o -I.
    ar rvs core/libcore.a core/core.o

app/libapp.a: app/app.cpp app/app.h core/core.h core/core.cpp
    g++ -c app/app.cpp -o app/app.o -I.
    ar rvs app/libapp.a app/app.o
    
clean:
    rm -f core/core.o app/app.o core/libcore.a app/libapp.a main
```

Python package `dummy` has the same layout as the C++ library. All `__init__.pxd` are empty. The library files are:

- `dummy/core/py_core.pxd`:

```
cdef extern from "core/core.h":
    cdef void greet()
```

- `dummy/core/py_core.pyx`:

```
from .py_core cimport greet as cpp_greet

def call_greet():
    cpp_greet()
```

- `dummy/app/py_app.pxd`:

```
cdef extern from "app/app.h":
    cdef int getTheAnswer()
```

- `dummy/app/py_app.pyx`:

```
from .py_app cimport getTheAnswer

def get_the_answer():
    return getTheAnswer()
```

- `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension(
        "dummy.core.py_core", [
            "dummy/core/py_core.pyx", 
            "cpp_src/core/core.cpp"
        ], include_dirs=["cpp_src"], language="c++"),
    Extension(
        "dummy.app.py_app", [
            "dummy/app/py_app.pyx",
            "cpp_src/app/app.cpp",
            # "cpp_src/core/core.cpp"  # <-- if uncomment this, everything will work well
        ], include_dirs=["cpp_src"], language="c++")
]

setup(name="dummy", version="1.0", packages=find_packages(), zip_safe=False,
      ext_modules=cythonize(extensions))
```

Now, if we call the `py_core` extension, everything is ok:

```
$ python -c "from dummy.core.py_core import call_greet; call_greet()"
Hello from core
```

However, if we call the `py_app` extension, we fail since `someServiceFun()` is defined in `libcore`, called by `getTheAnswer()` and not found in `libapp`:

```
$ python -c "from dummy.app.py_app import get_the_answer; get_the_answer()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ***/dummy/app/py_app.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _Z14someServiceFunv
```

---

I understand, that Cython builds shared libs, and the extension `py_app` know nothing about the dependencies inside `cpp` files (not `pyx`, but `cpp` those are wrapped by). Is it possible to provide this information to Cython in some way?

Right now I see four ways:

1. Compile `libcore` inside each extension (that is like adding `cpp_src/core/core.cpp` to the second extension in the example above). However, this means object files growth, code duplicating and other smelling stuff.
2. Compile a single monolith extension for the whole library. This way is even worse then the first one, since in real library there is a bunch of namespaces. Moreover, different models may b developed by different people, so naming collisions, as well as the monolith Cython extension, will become a mess very soon.
3. Compile `cpp`*`src`* manually and link explicitly `libcore` and `libapp` into the extensions appropriately by calling `Extension(..., libraries=["libcore", "libapp"])`. The key downside of this approach is that then I need to take into account compilation under various platforms (Windows, Linux, OS X) and difficulties with distribution. Since most users know only Python, I want to minimize the installation complexity to something like `pip install my_library`.
4. Manually referencing the shared lib. Not a good hack, since the library names are subject to change between different platforms and architectures. And actually I failed doing this (maybe doing something wrong, but including `libraries=["py_core.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu"], library_dirs=["dummy/core"]` caused linking error due to the library not found).

What I actually want, is to say "Hey, Cython, if you need something from `py_app` extension, please, load also a shared lib from the `py_core` extension and find all the missing symbols in it". Is it possible?